# Change device settings with ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework

I am writing an hybrid mobile app with ionic.
I can test my application in browser with this command:

```
ionic serve
```

But I see my app in full browser width and height.
I saw on some tutorial a screen inside the browser that shows a mobile screen, where I can change screen size, orientation and other options.
I do not manage to open this kind of layout in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Device Mode of the Chrome Dev Tools:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Or.. the Safari Web Inspector

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: great ! Do you know if there is the same thing in safari ?

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use

```
ionic serve --lab
```